# 404 not found for laravel for delete form

Tags: laravel, forms

**This is the controller page!**

```
  /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param \App\URI $URI
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(URI $URI)
    {
        $URI->deleted();
        return redirect('/p');
    }
```

**This is route below !**

```
    Route::patch('/page/{URI}','PageController@destroy');
```

**this is the blade page code below**

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
<tr>
    <td><a href="/page/{{ $page->URI }}">{{$page->title}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="/page/{{ $page->URI }}">{{$page->URI}}</td>
    <td><a href="/page/{{ $page->URI }}/edit">Modify</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{url('deletePage')}}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: lmao you with dwarf-champion? i saw your name in github branch

Answer (score 1):

A `DELETE` request is different from `GET` and `PATCH`. For deleting-routes, you should be using the `DELETE` route method instead, and submit a form with the `DELETE` method. You should also define a name with your route, so you can use named routes.

The route should be

```php
Route::delete('/page/{URI}', 'PageController@destroy')->name('page.destroy')";
```

Then you need to make your delete button submit a form.

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/page/{{ $page->URI }}">{{$page->title}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="/page/{{ $page->URI }}">{{$page->URI}}</td>
        <td><a href="/page/{{ $page->URI }}/edit">Modify</a></td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route("page.destroy", $URI) }}">
                @csrf
                @method("DELETE")
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            </form>
            <!-- <a href="{{url('deletePage')}}">Delete</a> -->
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Note that you could just be using [resourceful routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers), and you'll get all the routes you need for a resourceful controller. Then, instead of specifying each route manually, just do

```
Route::resource('page', 'PageController');
```

Laravel will handle the rest for you, and provide you with all the routes you need for a RESTfull controller.

Then you can also use named routes in your table,

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ route("page.show", $URI) }}">{{$page->title}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route("page.show", $URI) }}">{{$page->URI}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route("page.edit", $URI) }}">Modify</a></td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route("page.destroy", $URI) }}">
                @csrf
                @method("DELETE")
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: lmao im late xD

Answer (score 0):

suggesting to use delete `Route::delete('/page/{URI}','PageController@destroy');`

```
Route::delete('/page/{URI}','PageController@destroy')->name('page.destroy');
Route::get('/page/{URI}','PageController@show')->name('page.show');
Route::get('/page/{URI}/edit','PageController@edit')->name('page.edit');
Route::patch('/page/{URI}','PageController@update')->name('page.update');
```

here assummed you using model binding in controller :

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
<tr>
    <td><a href="{{route('page.show', $page)}}">{{$page->title}}</a></td> //guessing this is page_show
    <td><a href="{{route('page.show', $page)}}">{{$page->URI}}</td> //guessing this is page_show 
    <td><a href="{{route('page.edit', $page)}}">Modify</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

use last column for deleting data like this:

```
<td>
  <form action="{{route('page.destroy', $page)}}" method="POST" 
    onsubmit="return confirm('delete data?');">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('delete')}}
    <input type="submit" value="delete">
  </form>
</td>
```